# Uninstall Redis CentOS 7

Tags: linux, redis, centos7

I installed Redis a long time ago on my CentOS 7 VPS.
Now I want to remove the current version (3.0.5) and install the latest Redis 3.2.5.

How can I remove the current version?

I installed a time ago using the following commands:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.5.tar.gz

tar xzf redis-3.0.5.tar.gz

cd redis-3.0.5

make

make test

make install

cd utils

chmod +x install_server.sh

./install_server.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

1 - Stop redis

`/etc/init.d/redis_6379 stop`

2 - Remove all files

`rm -fr etc/redis/ /var/log/redis_* /etc/init.d/redis_6379 /usr/local/bin/redis*`

3 - Remove all data

`rm -fr /var/lib/redis/6379`

4 - Add the EPEL repository, and update YUM to confirm your change

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum update
```

5 - Install Redis

`sudo yum install redis`

6 - Start Redis

`sudo systemctl start redis`

7 - To automatically start Redis on boot

`sudo systemctl enable redis`

## https://serverfault.com/questions/817880/uninstall-redis-centos-7

Comment: $ systemctl status redis.service
● redis.service - Redis persistent key-value database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d
           └─limit.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-03-08 11:12:34 GMT; 14s ago
  Process: 129223 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf --supervised systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 129223 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Getting following error when starting redis

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this isn't an upgrade with live data migration, simply download the latest and greatest and follow the same procedure to install it over the current version.

Comment: Thanks! This does not work. I tried that, but in that case I still see the old version 3.0.5

Comment: Did you stop the old server?

Comment: How exactly? I just followed the steps like above again. After that I checked all folders using `find . -type d` I still found the old 3.0.5 version.

Comment: The install will not delete the old version's directory, it'll just replace the binaries in at the (default) installation location. Per the discussion at serverfault, you can just kill the old server process and then start the service again... or reboot :)